# Android user-permission to access Internet

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to connect to the Internet to access my server from my android application but it doesn't seem to be working. I looked online and found that I had to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

right before `</manifest>`. But when I am doing so, the compiler is showing a warning:

```
<uses-permission> tag appears after <application> tag   AndroidManifest.xml
```

Not sure if this warning is causing my code not to work. I tried placing the `<user-permission>` before the `<application>` but it still was showing the same warning. What does it imply?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've got it placed between `uses-sdk` and `application`, works for me.

Try to clean your project perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Should go after the `uses-sdk` and the `application` elements, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the uses-permission tag to before the application tag should have removed the warning. Try doing a clean on your project if you are using Eclipse.

Are you getting a runtime error about the internet permission when you run your app? What isn't working exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use it inside `manifest` tag:

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    ...
 </manifest>
```

Answer (score -1):

You also need this permission: android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Comment: Wrong, unless he's trying to connect only on wifi for instance.